# W/FirebasePerformance: PerfMetricValidator check failed, dropping the log. in Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I added firebase performance to my android app. 
I keep getting this error in my log cat when I run in on Marshmallow.

`W/FirebasePerformance: PerfMetricValidator check failed, dropping the log.`

and my network call aren't working. But it work fine in Kit Kat.

How do I resolve it and get my network calls to work in Marshmallow?

Comment: the `W/` means a warning not an error you have a problem some where else

Comment: So how do I figure out where the error is?

Comment: try to debug the firebase messaging service your application and check if the notification is received but not showing the notification or not received

Comment: Did you write any code that calls Firebase Performance Monitoring APIs?  Is there anything else in the log around that one line?  What do you mean by "my network call aren't working"?

Comment: That warning typically follows other warnings about which particular pieces of data are invalid. You can look at only FirebasePerformance messages by filtering: logcat FirebasePerformance:V *:S

Comment: @DougStevenson I didn't write any code that calls the Firebase Performance Monitoring API's. What I mean by net work call not working is, when I click a button the loads a view via a network call, it does work. Where as it used to work prior to add the performance monitoring api.

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow is going to help too much here, so I'll suggest that you open up a support ticket with Firebase support so they can dig into the problem more deeply.  If you can come up with a bare minimal app that reproduces the problem, that will help.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/